# Flex to remote server

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework

I am trying to get a Flex/PHP application set up and am having problems connecting to my server. The database/PHP isn't going to be hosted on a local server, it will be hosted on a remote server along side the PHP. When I am trying to set up the project, I am asked for the web root but when I put in the ftp or URL to the remote server it throws the "The web server document root is not a valid directory". All information I have found seem to be pointing to having a locally hosted version of the server, but that isn't possible. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are after here.  Are you looking to setup a server that accesses the database remotely or are you just looking to test locally and put up to server after?

Comment: Are you setting up the project using Flash Builder?  Or are you asking about some other tool?

Comment: right - so the flex will run from one machine and the php from another? you'll quickly run into security issues with flex.

Comment: I am using flash builder, so does the standard development workflow for flash builder involve having the database hosted locally?